# momentjs won't get difference between two dates

Tags: momentjs

I'm trying to get the difference between now and an end date in minutes. I have two date variables, but when i try to subtract them, it says `Property 'diff' does not exist on type 'string'.`

console.log(now) outputs: `November 24th 2019, 11:13:32`

console.log(endDate) outputs: `November 24th 2019, 12:25:10`

so the values are in date format.

I appreciate any help

```
let endDateTime = moment
  .unix(parseInt(auctionEndDateTime))
  .format("MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss");


let start=moment(Date.now());
let end=moment(endDateTime);
let duration = moment.duration(end.diff(start));
let hours = duration.asHours();


console.log('hours ' + hours);
console.log('days ' + duration.asDays());
```

Comment: `format` takes a moment time object and returns a string matching the defined format.  
If you want to perform calculations on the time objects, don't convert them to strings.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// you can get the difference between two days with javascript Date class

let firstDate = new Date('Sun Nov 24 2019 17:28:33'); //new Date('2019-11-12');
let secondDate = new Date('Tue Nov 26 2019 17:28:33');//new Date('2019-11-20');

let milliSFirst = firstDate.getTime();
let milliSSecond = secondDate.getTime();

console.log("diff in days " + (milliSSecond - milliSFirst)/(1000 * 3600 * 24) )
```

```js
// take the dates as milliseconds and then you can do the calculations

let start=moment(Date.now());
let end=moment(Date.now() + 1000 * 3600 * 24 );
let duration = moment.duration(end.diff(start));
let hours = duration.asHours();
 
 
console.log('hours ' + hours);
console.log('days ' + duration.asDays());
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/moment/moment/2.2.1/min/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I got it working. Your momentjs example helped.